# How to read string as hex number in bash?

Tags: bash, numeric-data, hex, expr

I have the bash line:

```
expr substr $SUPERBLOCK 64 8
```

Which is return to me string line:

```
00080000
```

I know that this is, actually, a 0x00080000 in little-endian. Is there a way to create integer-variable from it in bash in big-endian like 0x80000?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably a better way to do this but I've come up with this solution which converts the number to decimal and then back to hex (and manually adds the `0x`):

```
printf '0x%x\n' "$((16#00080000))"
```

Which you could write as:

```
printf '0x%x\n' "$((16#$(expr substr "$SUPERBLOCK" 64 8)))"
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually added |rev inside to convert to big-endian: printf "$((16#$(expr substr $SUPERBLOCK 64 8|rev)))"

Comment: @DenisNovac I'm not sure if you use big/little endian correctly (maybe you have something else on mind, but I'm doing some assembly programming for fun, so for me endianness is per bytes), but 0x12345678 is in other endianness 0x78563412, not 0x87654321. (and the value in your question `00080000` is after byte swap `00000800`, i.e. 2048 decimal)

Comment: Oh, you are right. I just got the right answer by wrong way. I am rewriting some code from python to bash, so i know all answers before i got them.

Comment: @DenisNovac: You didn't have the right answer FYI.  0x8000 was originally in your question which is not the same as 0x80000 or 0x00080000

Comment: Yes, but i needed to get exactly 0x8000, so i've made mistake somewhere before. This is offset or something.

Comment: If you need 0x8000 you are also looking to change the value of the number completely?

Comment: 0x00080000 = 524288, 0x8000 = 32768

Comment: Actually, that was an offset mistake. To read the right number i need to write "expr substr $SUPERBLOCK 65 8" and this is 0x00800000, which is, in big-endian, gives 0x8000 (i checked it on more specific field such as checksum, where no zeros around). But now i need a way to reverse string by two chars pairs or somehow convert between big-endian and little-endian.

Comment: So this is how i do it for 8 bytes hex number: v="$(expr substr $SUPERBLOCK 65 8)"\
s="${v:6:2}${v:4:2}${v:2:2}${v:0:2}"\
BLOCKS_PER_GROUP="$((16#$s))"

Comment: instead of  >>printf '0x%x\n' "$((16#00080000))"<< is better to 
>> printf '0x%x\n' "0x00080000"<<

Answer (score 5):

There are two more or less standard (and ancient) command-line unix tools that offer very easy ways to convert numbers between different bases:

```
$ { echo '16'; echo i; echo 00080000; echo p; } | dc
524288
$ { echo 'ibase=16'; echo 00080000; } | bc  
524288
```

For normal human use I very much prefer `bc`, but when writing a program that generates code, especially from a parser of some sort, a stack-based tool like `dc` may be easier to deal with (and indeed the original version of `bc` was a front-end parser for `dc`).